# SVG scale by (100% - 60px)

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to build an SVG image with content that is 100% the width of the container, minus 60px for some text.

If I was using HTML, or SVG with javascript, I would have no problem doing this. But I feel like there should be a way to do this using SVG (and CSS if needed).

I want the equivalent of this ([Codepen here](https://codepen.io/jkjustjoshing/pen/qBdeRjp)):

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <rect fill="#ccc" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>

  <text x="100%" y="50%" stroke="black" text-anchor="end">Y-axis</text>

  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <!-- This rect represents the entirety of the contents of the graph -->
    <rect x="0" y="0" style="width: calc(100% - 60px)" height="100%" fill="#c88"></rect>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

In the above snippet, the inner `<rect>` resizes to be `100% - 60px` the width of the container element. However, this trick only works for a single element - if you replace that `<rect>` with a complex SVG structure it no longer works.

[image]

Things I've tried:

1. Doing a `transform: scale()` via CSS on the `<rect>` - I can't figure out what to put into the `scale()` to make it behave like `100% - 60px`.
2. Changing the width of the nested `<svg>` element

   - `<svg width="calc(100% - 60px)">` doesn't work - can't do `calc()` inside the `width` attribute
   - `<svg width="100%" style="width: calc(100% - 60px);">` (with or without the `width` attribute) - doesn't work - the CSS "width" property is ignored whether or not the `width` attribute is present.

I'm starting to think what I want to do isn't possible right now with SVG, but it doesn't seem like an uncommon use case. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'll have to think this over, as transforming a `<g>` would squish your graphics… Could you possibly wrap your `<svg> in a block with `padding-right: 60px`, and add `overflow: visible` to the `<svg>` to make the SVG's box fit while having the possibility of making your text plop outside the `100% - 60px` box? A bit hacky, I reckon (and there are probably people who have already solved this better) but maybe it'll help.

Comment: @HereticMonkey a `<rect>` can't have children in SVG

Comment: @chriskirknielsen I *do* want to squish my inner graphics, just not the outer graphics. a `<g transform>` is exactly what I want, but I don't know what to put *inside* the `transform` to make it behave like this. The `padding-right` idea is really neat - gonna have to play with that.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Sadly you cannot apply an absolute scale, I believe. It'll always be relative to the source element (I have wished for something like `transform: scaleX(200px)` in CSS in the past). This is the best I can offer: [View on CodePen](https://codepen.io/chriskirknielsen/pen/xxGvqVy).

Comment: @chriskirknielsen I'm definitely going to try making this work! If you write it up as a full-fledged answer I'll mark it as the accepted solution (assuming there isn't some magic solution neither of us are aware of that someone proposes before that).

Comment: I hope someone comes along with a better solution, SVG is such an amazing technology, I'm sure there's *something!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you might have some luck achieving the same by making your graph area 100% of the viewBox, but place the SVG in a container with `60px` of padding on the right to account for the text space.

Moving your text (and background `rect`) to `x="100%"` with its `text-anchor="start"`, in addition to letting the SVG overflow, you can get a pretty close result without needing to transform your graphic, since you have a fixed `60px` value you can consistently rely on:

```css
div {
  padding-right: 60px;
}
svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <rect fill="#ccc" x="100%" y="0" width="60px" height="100%"></rect>

    <text x="100%" y="50%" stroke="black" text-anchor="start">Y-axis</text>

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#c88"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

PS: Maybe you would prefer your text to have `text-anchor="middle"`, and transform it in CSS with `transform: translateX(30px)` to place it in the centre of the "text" area — might look cleaner that way:

```css
div {
  padding-right: 60px;
}
svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
text {
  transform: translateX(30px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <rect fill="#ccc" x="100%" y="0" width="60px" height="100%"></rect>

    <text x="100%" y="50%" stroke="black" text-anchor="middle">Y-axis</text>

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#c88"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```